# Most stable configuration for NFS between new Linux and ancient Solaris?

Tags: solaris, redhat, nfs

I am trying to mix the very old with the new.  I have read that there are some nfs parameters that you can tweak to improve stability and compatibility.  I don't care about speed at all, what would be the optimum settings for a stable and compatible nfs setup?

I have four Sun Ultra 5 boxes that share folders with nfs and have no problem at all.  I am trying both share to and mount from a Red Hat EL3 box.  There are major problems here.  On the Linux side, shares will become unmounted, but they can become remounted if nfs.server is restarted on the Solaris side.  Even worse, sometimes the Solaris nfs hangs when trying to mount the Linux share on bootup, making the box unable to boot.  The RH box is owned by a different department, so changes on the Sun side would be easier for me to make.

Comment: RHEL3 is new?  Its running a 2.4 kernel and was released in 2003.  Linux NFS has matured quite a bit since that period.  Sorry I don't have any tips or answers for you.

Comment: The Sun boxes are running Solaris 2.6 which I believe was released in 1998.  So for me, RHEL3 is new.

Answer (score 1):

Export your share with async option (to avoid IOBOUND errors).

```
Example /etc/exports on server:
/nfsshare      192.168.1.0/24(rw,async)
```

Mount up the share on the client with intr and soft for the restarting problem.

```
Example /etc/fstab entry on client:
server:/nfsshare   /mnt/nfsshare      nfs    intr,soft,async
```